# Convert IQueryable object to a List and add a new Item

Tags: asp.net

I have the following IQueryable object:

```
        var user = from d in _context.Users
        join userRole in _context.UserRoles on d.Id equals userRole.UserId
        join role in _context.Roles on userRole.RoleId equals role.Id
        where role.Name == "Liquidador"
        select d;
```

Which then is send as a ViewBag to the View:

```
        ViewBag.UserID = new SelectList(user.AsNoTracking(), "UserName", "Name", selectedUser);
```

**The Problem:**

I need to add a new Item to the result of the IQueryable. So I've proceeded like this:

```
var UserNameList = user.Select(s => new { s.Name, s.UserName }).ToList();
```

However, I'm missing something when I'm trying to add the new item:

```
UserNameList.Insert(0, new *NewWhat?* { Name = "Liquidador", UserName = "--Select--"} );
```

Usually I declare a new element of a specific model but in this case I don't know which model to declare for this IQueryable. Any recomendations?

Thanks

*EDIT:*

The IQueryable object goes to the Get Method of the View as part of a function:

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> Management()
    {
        PopulateUserDropDownList();

        var Tiendas = await _context.Stores.ToListAsync();
        StoreEmployee model = new StoreEmployee
        {
            Stores = Tiendas
        };

        return View(model);
    }
```

This list is then presented in a dropdownlist, inside a table:

```
        <td class="col-md-2">
            <div class="form-group" form="@(String.Format("{0}{1}","form",item.StoreID))">
               <div>
                <select asp-for="@item.Usuario" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.UserId" form="@(String.Format("{0}{1}","form",item.StoreID))"></select>
                <span asp-validation-for="@item.Usuario" class="text-danger"></span>
               </div>
            </div>
        </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems it would be cleaner if you define a class `UserDTO` (or any other name that likes you more)

```
public class UserDTO
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

and then you do

```
var UserNameList = user
  .Select(s => new UserDTO { Name = s.Name, UserName = s.UserName })
  .ToList();

UserNameList.Insert(0, new UserDTO { Name = "Liquidador", UserName = "--Select--"} );
```

OTOH... smells a little to add the empty element as part of the data array, my recommendation is to handle that on razor view and just send `UserNameList` with real data. Dropdown razor methods contains overloads to specify the empty element text.

If you show your HTML, we may help you to implement a better solution.

Comment: Information added, Claudio. Is it enough to try the other aproach?